# How can i use loop to show the data distribution in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, data-science

I am a beginner
How can i use for loop to print all them

```
['MSZoning', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities',
   'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2',
   'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st',
   'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation',
   'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2',
   'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', 'KitchenQual',
   'Functional', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond',
   'PavedDrive', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition']
```

Like I did in it

```py
pd.concat([df['MSZoning'].value_counts()/df.shape[0] * 100, 
           df3['MSZoning'].value_counts()/df3.shape[0] * 100], axis=1,
          keys=['MSZoning_org','MSZoning_clean'])
```

output:-

![output][https://i.stack.imgur.com/trH9m.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

```
xs = ['MSZoning', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities',
   'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2',
   'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st',
   'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation',
   'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2',
   'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', 'KitchenQual',
   'Functional', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond',
   'PavedDrive', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition']

def cat_var_dist(var):
    return pd.concat([
        df[var].value_counts()/df.shape[0] * 100, 
        df3[var].value_counts()/df3.shape[0] * 100,
        ], 
        axis=1,
        keys=[f'{var}_org',f'{var}_clean'],
    )

for x in xs:
    print(cat_var_dist(x))
```

Comment: and can i use this function in that loop ```def cat_var_dist(var):
    return pd.concat([df['MSZoning'].value_counts()/df.shape[0] * 100,
                    df3['MSZoning'].value_counts()/df3.shape[0] * 100], axis=1,
                    keys=[var+'_org',var+'_clean'])```

Comment: Yes! As updated.

Comment: but how ? can you please show me

Comment: I have updated the answer using the function inside a for loop